# After Windows 10 upgrade (from Windows 8 Home), error "The file '' could not be found." when Eclipse is default editor for a file type

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, windows-10

After Windows 10 upgrade (from Windows 8 Home), I'm getting an error "The file '' could not be found." when trying to open a file by doulble-clicking in File Explorer with default editor set as Eclipse. This is happening once the workspace is loaded.

If Eclipse is closed, double-clicking on the file prompts for workspace first, and then the file loads correctly in Eclipse editor. However after Eclipse is running, the above error is observed.

Steps tried: removed Eclipse and set up again; changed default editor for file types with issue (.java, .jsp), and set to Eclipse again.
This issue did not exist in Windows 8.

Comment: That may be related to how you can only have one instance of Eclipse open at any given time.